# How do check whether a shopify product option is unavailable

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have a dropdown menu to select specific sizes and I want to show sizes with zero quantity as disabled.

```
{% for value in option.values %}
<option
  value="{{ value | escape }}"
  {% if option.selected_value == value %}selected="selected"{% endif %}
  {{ value }}
</option>
{% endfor %}
```

The questions I have seen on SO all check if `variant.available` or something equivalent but I want to know if there is a way to check if a particular option is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `variant.available` is a better option to check it is available or not
something like this one

```
<select name="id" id="ProductSelect--{{ section.id }}" class="product-single__variants no-js">
   {% for variant in product.variants %}
   {% if variant.available %}
      <option {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant %}
         selected="selected" {% endif %}
         data-sku="{{ variant.sku }}"
         value="{{ variant.id }}">
         {{ variant.title }} - {{ variant.price | money_with_currency }}
      </option>
   {% else %}
      <option disabled="disabled">
         {{ variant.title }} - {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}
      </option>
   {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: `variant.available` isn't working, I think it is because I have multiple product options.

Comment: Yes, but this is the master `select` tag, and mostly hidden into Shopify themes it works. but the theme used different variant `select` boxes or custom boxes for better representation.